# PouchDB remote replicate to 404 not found

Tags: android, cordova, pouchdb

I am getting 404 error from pouchDB when creating and replicating to remote couchDB, running from a cordova app.  Not sure next step for testing.

I have found a number of references with this error when creating a local instance, however my local instance is working great this is occurring when trying to replicate to remote server.

```
    var readingTime = new PouchDB('reading_time');
    var readingTimeServer = new PouchDB(serverHost + 'reading_time');
    initReadingTimeStats();

    function initReadingTimeStats(){        
      var replicateReadingTimeToServer = readingTime.replicate.to(readingTimeServer, {live: true});     

      replicateReadingTimeToServer.on("error", function(err){
      console.log("!!!!!!!!Reading time replication error: " + err);
    });
}
```

In chrome console I see:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
....:5984/reading_time/?_nonce=3j0jadvieUjp9xtb
```

when creating pouchDB instance, the web link does work from PC and the android 4.4 device testing on.  And every minute (60000 timeout) I see:

```
Reading time replication error: {"status":404,"name":"not_found"}
```

When adding entry into the local readingTime, I get success:

```
Object {ok: true, id: "F42D5BEB-513F-E8EE-878C-861E69C770B7", rev: "1-7933e17d149aa8786382de64284f58f6"}
```

This is then followed with another attempt to sync which gives same 404 error.  Following the link to the remote instance number of docs stays at 0 so its definitely not syncing

Comment: What version of CouchDB are you using? That 404 used to be a common error with Cloudant, but it's been fixed in recent versions. As a test, you can set `{ajax: {cache: false}}` (see [the docs](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#create_database)) to disable that `nonce` parameter and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: {"couchdb":"Welcome","uuid":"dd0939ace7e17d2ce68a38b1b4a403b9","version":"1.5.0","vendor":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"14.04"}}

Comment: Hey thanks for quick reply, so I have added cache false to pouchDB instance.  ...:5984/reading_time/ Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - Nonce removed but still having same error (Reading time console.log as well) Version number above (1.5.0)

Comment: @nlawson I installed pouchdb via bower have tried both 3.0.6 and 3.6.0 any help would be great thanks

Comment: @nlawson Ok so I have found when I set cordova to 4.0.0 it adds platform targeting 19 and works and syncs to couchdb.  When I install cordova 5.0.0 targeting 22 it gives error as above.  Ideally I would like to use 5.0.0 as we are using crosswalk and can add as plugin